# UKF for radar implementation

Tags: ros, kalman-filter

I'm struggling to implement Unscented Kalman Filter for tracking objects using radar. My state vector contains [x y z vx vy vz] and I can measure [rho phi theta velocity]. So everything looks trivial at the begging, because state estimation is simply

```
  x = rho * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
  y = rho * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
  z = rho * cos(theta);
  vx = v * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
  vy = v * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
  vz = v * cos(theta);
```

Measurement model is also well-known:

```
rho = sqrt(p_x*p_x + p_y*p_y + p_z*p_z);         
phi = atan(p_y/p_x); 
theta = atan(sqrt(p_x*p_x + p_y*p_y)/p_z); 
velocity = sqrt(v_x*v_x + v_y*v_y + v_z*v_z);
```

My predictions are based on the constant velocity model and looks like this:

```
    //predicted state values
    px_p = p_x + v_x*delta_t;
    py_p = p_y + v_y*delta_t;
    pz_p = p_z + v_z*delta_t;
    vx_p = v_x + err_x*delta_t;
    vy_p = v_y + err_y*delta_t;
    vz_p = v_z + err_z*delta_t;
```

And... it doesn't work. The only one case when it is working is constant velocity along x-axis with. Could anyone explain me what am I doing wrong? What should be Q-matrix in this case? Appreciate any tips and hints. Cheers, Vicky.

---

UPD: In the robot_localization package I found matrix named transferFunction_(), which is in my understanding the process function (in the reference example in the comments it's used for prediction sigma points), without noise. It's 15-dimentional and implemented like this:

```
double roll = state_(StateMemberRoll);
double pitch = state_(StateMemberPitch);
double yaw = state_(StateMemberYaw);

double sp = ::sin(pitch);
double cp = ::cos(pitch);
double cpi = 1.0 / cp;
double tp = sp * cpi;

double sr = ::sin(roll);
double cr = ::cos(roll);

double sy = ::sin(yaw);
double cy = ::cos(yaw);

transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVx) = cy * cp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVy) = (cy * sp * sr - sy * cr) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVz) = (cy * sp * cr + sy * sr) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberAx) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVx) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberAy) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVy) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberAz) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVz) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVx) = sy * cp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVy) = (sy * sp * sr + cy * cr) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVz) = (sy * sp * cr - cy * sr) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberAx) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVx) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberAy) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVy) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberAz) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberY, StateMemberVz) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVx) = -sp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVy) = cp * sr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVz) = cp * cr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberAx) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVx) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberAy) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVy) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberAz) = 0.5 * transferFunction_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberVz) * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVroll) = delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVpitch) = sr * tp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberVyaw) = cr * tp * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberPitch, StateMemberVpitch) = cr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberPitch, StateMemberVyaw) = -sr * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberYaw, StateMemberVpitch) = sr * cpi * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberYaw, StateMemberVyaw) = cr * cpi * delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberVx, StateMemberAx) = delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberVy, StateMemberAy) = delta;
transferFunction_(StateMemberVz, StateMemberAz) = delta;
```

There is also clear processNoiseCovariance matrix:

```
processNoiseCovariance_.setZero();
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberX, StateMemberX) = 0.05;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberY, StateMemberY) = 0.05;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberZ, StateMemberZ) = 0.06;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberRoll, StateMemberRoll) = 0.03;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberPitch, StateMemberPitch) = 0.03;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberYaw, StateMemberYaw) = 0.06;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVx, StateMemberVx) = 0.025;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVy, StateMemberVy) = 0.025;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVz, StateMemberVz) = 0.04;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVroll, StateMemberVroll) = 0.01;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVpitch, StateMemberVpitch) = 0.01;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberVyaw, StateMemberVyaw) = 0.02;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberAx, StateMemberAx) = 0.01;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberAy, StateMemberAy) = 0.01;
processNoiseCovariance_(StateMemberAz, StateMemberAz) = 0.015;
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please be more specific? What is that does not work? What did you try? Could you please share more code? State and Measures are certainly useful, but we need to have more information in order to help you and more code to look at.

Comment: Hi @Emanuele, by "doesn't work" I mean tracking/prediction of the next state. I tried to start with 2D, [here is an example:](https://www.haidynmcleod.com/unscented-kalman-filter), but when I'm adding additional z-variables to my state and _theta_ to measurements results are no longer predictable. Code is mostly the same from the link, except for state, measurements model, process error covariance (Q), and measurements error covariance (R).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. I took a look at the example code you are following and I saw that it is using a combination of a lidar and a radar. If you are trying to add additional variables, you need to take in consideration to retrieve the current state and the control input of the new state. Basically your column vector will change and a different covariance matrix need to be evaluated. The example assumes a probability model for each sensor which is good. The part, in your case, that is missing is dealing with the new state and the new covariance matrix.

Comment: How to do that? First I would look into [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/12642/calculating-covariances-of-robots-odometry/) which could be of help. Also in the example code I would add an additional set of state that will take care of the aspect you are trying to deal with. Another useful resource that could help you understand how to do that is [this one](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html). That is a valuable tool for understanding both EFK and UKF and how to properly add variables.

Comment: @Emanuele, thanks a lot for references, I'm taking look at those right now. The difference from the example is that I only use radar and it's static, at this point I'm not sure how odometry can be helpful. Another idea I have is that noise terms (err_x, err_y, err_z) should be used actually err_xyz, err_v.  What do you mean, when you are saying "different covariance"? I only initialize it (the augmented by 2 additional columns and 2 rows) at the beginning as identity matrix, I thought math stay the same, am I correct?

Comment: @Emanuele, I've just realized that instead my noise term should be err_x is the squared longitudinal acceleration noise, err_y is the squared yaw acceleration noise and err_z is squared pitch acceleration noise. And that's why I can't just multiply my linear speed by those. I'll check if it helps.

Comment: @Emanuele, I've updated the question, thanks for great reference to robot_localization. However, I'm still a little bit confused because everything is based here is cased on roll-pitch-yaw and I don't have roll-measurement, so should I just say that it's zero and just recalculate the rest of the elements? Is it possible to cut off state vector and then update transferFunction members accordingly?

Comment: Can my theta and phi of the object be used as pitch and yaw ?

Comment: Hi Victoria, ok I saw the updates and they look good. Yes it is possible to use theta and phi of the object as pitch and yaw. for example: if you start a callback for the radar of a vector of 3 states (x,y,z), nothing forbids us to declare the same vector but carrying 6 states (x,y,z, roll, pitch, yaw). The first three coordinates will be used by the radar for some predetermined operations, but the remaining states can be re-used as roll-pitch-yaw. I will send you in the next 5 min an example of how I implemented that. One sec

Comment: Ok I created [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yktst1xnfffbuc9/pf_first_order.h?dl=0) a Dropbox folder where you can see how to do that specific callback. In my case I had a sensor that was giving me x-y-z and by declaring a 6 state vector I was able to re-use the extra parameters as roll-pitch-yaw. Go to line 239 at the callback function `void usblCb(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)` and you will see the 3 state vector declared as 6.

Comment: @Emanuele, yes, I can see that and I can understand the idea. My main concern at the moment is right adjustment of  transferFunction. Could you clarify this for me? So if the roll is 0, is `transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVy) = (cy * sp * sr - sy * cr) * delta` will be `transferFunction_(StateMemberX, StateMemberVy) = - sy * delta` because sin(roll) is 0 and cos(roll) is 1 or I shouldn't use roll at all?

Comment: Sure, ok from the example you are following and given that the model does not move in all direction freely like a vessel or an airplane, your degree of freedom are limited, in your case roll could be neglected because the roll angle is very small. But if the car is traveling at a considerable speed, than you need to consider it.

Comment: @Emanuele, I've been testing using 15-dimentional state vector and the transferFunction from the robot_localization, but still no success. I'm afraid that I'm doing something wrong. I'm almost sure that the math itself is correct, but my prediction model and/or measurement model is broken. My object is moving in all directions, but information I can get is limited. I only know how far it's from the radar (rho), the altitude which I can calculate from theta, x-y plane position - I get it from phi-angle and I also know radial velocity. Do you have maybe more reference links to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A radar measures only radial velocity so your measurement model is wrong.

Comment: That's why I'm using
 `vx = v * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
  vy = v * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
  vz = v * cos(theta); ` for prediction, where **v** is the radial velocity and later for the correction `velocity = sqrt(v_x*v_x + v_y*v_y + v_z*v_z);` which is also radial velocity.

Comment: your velocity ist the length of the full velocity vector, thats not what you measure

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I haven't found the solution, so I'm just running two UKF filters on 2 planes to cover 3D. Visual part works fine in rviz, but I'm still implementing data association algorithms to be sure that I'm tracking the same target with both filters.